# How can I save a PNG image greater than 90 KB?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray, tf.keras

I have an image, I am converting them into NumPy array. Then after some processing, I am saving those processed images into PNG using **save_img** command. I want to know how can I save only greater than 90KB images using the below code? I want to use "save_img" function

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import save_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
# load image as as RGB
img = load_img('bondi_beach.png')
# convert image to a numpy array
img_array = img_to_array(img)
# save the image with a new filename
save_img('bondi_beach_grayscale.png', img_array)
```

Comment: There is no built-in limit of 90KiB. Where are you seeing this limit? Are you getting an error message when you try saving a larger image?

Comment: @Dai actually I am not getting any error message. But I want to save the image if its size more than 90KB. Can you tell me from NumPy array, how can I calculate image weight (KB)? Then my problem will be solved.

Comment: What happens when you use your code as-is? Does it save the file or save only the first 90KB from?

Comment: I note that your code is saving JPEG files, not PNG files (`save_img` looks at the file extension to determine the output format unless you manually specify the `file_format` argument).

Comment: file format is not an issue. Can you tell me from NumPy array, how can I calculate image weight (KB)?

Comment: This must be an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). NumPy does not know how large the output file will be; compressing image data and saving it is done by keras, which in turn outsources it to PIL. Just save and first then check its size if you need to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below link: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator

This problem can be solved by using ImageDataGenerator. You no need to convert large dataset into memory rather access them as batches. Use model.flow_from_directory, model.fit_generator, etc. I am using mobile, hence unable to format it properly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am using the same code and my code is running perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the weight of an image using the below.

```
import os
print(os.stat('small_tree.png').st_size/1024,'KB')
```

Once you have the weights you can write a condition to save image or not depending upon the threshold size.
Hope this helps. Thanks